# Curl command does not work as expected with jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, curl

I am facing a weird issue when using curl in jenkins file. The api call is simple, just have to pass an authorization token to the api like below:

```
sh(script: "curl -u ${key}: https://mySonarQube/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=ProjectName", returnStdout: true)
```

This throws an error like below:

> an exception which occurred:
> in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
> in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@3fc99581
> in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
> in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@6ba4ed98
> in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
> in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@7caf7588
> in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
> in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@6a1f4c92
> in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
> in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@12b444a
> in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@12b444a
> Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
> at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1793)
> at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
> at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.writeObject(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1437)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor474.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
> at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:557)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:534)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:517)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:441)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
> at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
> at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Finished: FAILURE

It seems it fails at this point `Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap` but I dont know what happens behind the scene.

Its weird because when calling another api it works just fine. And if i open this api in browser I see json content in there which is just a regular json content.

Does anybody know what might be the issue ?

Comment: Can you run this same exact cURL command from the shell and tell us what the stdout/stderr is?  Also can you post the Jenkins version

Comment: The same command in CMD gives the correct json response. Jenkins ver is. 2.204.2

Comment: What is the  content-header of the response?

Comment: I had two curl calls one after another, always the first one works fine, second fails, after splitting them into two different steps they worked just fine. Its so weird what could be the issue. One hint that might help is that I was using sleep(time:10, unit:"SECONDS") in front of curl calls, I am not sure if that impacts the script in any way. For now I will just consider this as fixed because I am keeping them in different steps anyway. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more of a help